# SCSS how do I stop styling multiple <p> tags in a row when an <img> follows

Tags: javascript, css, sass

Basically, I have a list of

tags from a WYSIWYG editor that have a margin-bottom of 20px. However, if the sibling of the

tag has an  tag, I would like to remove that margin so that the  tag can set the margin. How would I do this?

This is my styling

```
.wysiwyg {
p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}
}
```

Basic markup

```
<div class="wysiwyg">
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    // Styling must stop here so that there is no bottom margin from the first above <p> tag
    <img />
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
    <p></p>
</div>
```

Comment: `.wysiwyg ~ p` will work in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tilde ~`, it will select all element after the current selector, and then reset the rule of all `p` after the `img`:

```
.wysiwyg {
  p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
  }
  img ~ p {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

Here a demo

```css
.wysiwyg p {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: red;
}

.wysiwyg img ~ p {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  background-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="wysiwyg">
    <p>1</p>
    <p>2</p>
    <p>3</p>
    <img />
    <p>4</p>
    <p>5</p>
    <p>6</p>
</div>
```

More information can be found **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_combinator)**

Comment: Hmmm that doesn't seem to select it?

Comment: `img` does not take any child!

Comment: Wait, I understand what you mean now. Well the thing is, AFTER the <img> tag, I would like to bring back the margin. I need the element directly before the <img> tag to be reset.

Answer (score 0):

Just set a negative `margin-top` for `img` tags that are preceded by a `p` tag:

```
.wysiwyg {
    p {
        margin-bottom: 20px;
    }
    p + img {
        margin-top: -20px;
    }
}
```